# Parse top followed pages

Tags: facebook, parsing, twitter, instagram, social-networking

I am specializing on parsing with Python and currently working on a sociological research. In my research I need to parse the most followed pages from any of the most popular social webs. I have run through their API and other methods to search for those and found out that most of them (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram) do not allow to make a search by the followers count or other information.

Have anyone had that problem? How did you overcome it? Is there any way to parse what I need (not only in above mentioned social webs, excluding YouTube)?

---

UPD: For research purposes i need several thousands of those.

Comment: It would seem that sites like this: http://friendorfollow.com/twitter/most-followers/ may be of use to get lists of the most followed users

Comment: That`s too few for my purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find an answer for twitter. Not very elegant but that`s what i needed.

If you need more than 1k certain bloggers (e.g. those with 1m followers or more), you can use the following algorithm:

1. Take one famous blogger (e.g. [@LeoDiCaprio](https://twitter.com/LeoDiCaprio)) and parse pages`
   ids he follows which have number of followers you need (in our case
   it`s >1m).
2. Add those pages  to a list, and then for each of `em
   make the same.

I think you`ve got the point.
Popular pages in most cases follows mostly the most popular ones, that`s why it will do the trick =) 
Because of twitters` API gives you only 15 requests per 15 mins, depending on count of pages you need, this job will take some time (for me it took 1 hour to get 1k pages)